# plot graph from python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i want to convert [that dataframe](https://data.gov.in/resources/housing-price-index-india-and-major-cities-considering-2010-11-q1100-upto-september-2013/download)
into this dataframe and plot a matplotlib graph using date along x axis
[changed dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyBIe.jpg)

Comment: Isn't this question a dupe of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161665/convert-dataframe-column-of-object-type-into-float?

Comment: how can i convert the dataframe into the 'changed dataframe'. I tried transpose function.but then i cant able to plot that dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.T.plot(kind='bar')`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('./housing_price_index_2010-11_100.csv')

df.T.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

you can also assign the transpose to a new variable and plot that (what you asked in the comment):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('./housing_price_index_2010-11_100.csv')

df_transposed = df.T
df_transposed.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

both result the same:

[image]

Comment: how can i convert the dataframe into the 'changed dataframe'. I tried transpose function.but then i cant able to plot that dataframe.

Comment: @ManafMh you may also "Accept" an answer when it fully answers your question

Comment: @ManafMh no I mean if the answer addresses your question accept it by clicking on the check mark [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) so that others notice it will work in the first look.